# A word that refers to spilling or splashing of ink?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there any word which refers to the spilling, splattering, sprinkling or splashing of ink? (Or something less “violent”, like the pouring or dripping of ink?)

Comment: You might try *smudge*, but that’s more of a rubbing out of existing ink.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sort of thing...

[image: Blots of black ink]

...is a ***blot***. Or several blots of ink, in this case. Also *inkblot*.

Image reference: http://chainink.blogspot.co.uk/2010_09_01_archive.html

Comment: Yet *blot* can also refer to the mopping up of ink.

Comment: @Robusto Isn't English wonderful? I'd forgotten that *blot* can have two almost diametrically-opposed uses, just as *cleave* can. Those are blots in the image, though.

Comment: The blobs of spilt ink can indeed be called *blots*, but as Robusto says, if OP speaks of having **blotted some ink** that's more likely to mean *used blotting paper to mop up excess/spilt ink*, rather than the spilling itself.

Comment: Hmm. It's a long time since I used such a pen, but "I made a blot" comes to mind.

Comment: Blot as a noun is what the OP is looking for. Blot as a verb means cleaning up the blot as a noun.

Comment: The phrase "He blotted his copy-book" has just come to mind. That doesn't mean that he mopped up some spilt ink. (Yes, it's normally figurative or metaphorical these days, but the origin is obvious)

Comment: Nice picture, nice answer, but not the best answer.

Comment: Rorschaching?  No, I just made that up.

Answer (score 11):

How about *[spatter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spatter)*? (Note, this is not the same as *splatter*.)

> spat·ter  (sptr) v. spat·tered, spat·ter·ing, spat·ters v.tr.
>   1. To scatter (a liquid) in drops or small splashes.

Comment: While this is a nice answer, I think it's worth mentioning that *spatter* and *splatter* are in fact related and nearly synonymous. The etymology of *splatter* given by my American Heritage Dictionary is "blend of *splash* and *spatter*". The other definitions of *spatter* given in that dictionary are "2. To spot, splash, or soil. 3. To sully the reputation of; defame." 2. could apply to nonliquids like dirt and 3. of course has nothing to do with liquid; whereas *splatter* has a strong (perhaps even inescapable) connotation of liquid.

Answer (score 8):

There are three common reasons why "traditional" ink ends up where you don't want it.

You accidentally knock over the ink-pot - normally described as **spilling** the ink.

Excess ink falls off the pen-nib en route from ink-pot to writing surface - you **dripped** the ink, resulting in a **blot** (noun), which you may blot (verb) with absorbent paper to stop it spreading.

An overloaded nib **pools** or **blobs** ink while you're actually writing.

But in practice today few people use quills or fountain pens where such mishaps can occur. Usually nowadays it's a cartridge pen or ballpoint, in which case the ink just **leaks**.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The first word that came to my mind was [**splotch**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=splotch&ls=a).

One [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ink+splotch%2Csplotch+of+ink%2C+dirt+splotch%2C+splotch+of+dirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) confirms that the word *splotch* is indeed coupled with the word *ink* in many contexts – more so than *dirt*.

Until today, however, I didn't realize that the word *splotch* also appears to be [chiefly American](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/splotch).

[Google images](http://www.google.com/search?q=ink+splotch&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=dl6FUJ7hMsPE0QGG0oHoCw&ved=0CB8QsAQ&biw=1165&bih=860), upon getting a query for *ink splotch*, will suggest *splatter, stain, splat, spot,* and *blotch* as alternatives to be partnered with *ink*.

Answer (score 3):

How about [dribble](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dribble), or [trickle](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/trickle)?